# I want to be a good person to invite to a party

Tags: grammar, adjectives, complements

Can we say this sentence is grammatically correct English?

> I want to be a good person to invite to a party.

The intended meaning is:

> I want to be a person who is good to invite to a party.

Thanks.

Comment: It's grammatically correct, but I think an improvement might be: _I want to be a person people want to invite to a party_.

Comment: What specifically are you having doubts about? This is the third question you've asked that involves an infinitive clause.

Comment: Yes, it is, which means that I have focused on infinitive clauses for a while and I think it is not forbidden to ask a specific type of question for more than one. I am reading linguistics researches and one of them said: "This sentence is wrong" but I don't understand why. @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: As I said, what *specifically* are you having doubts about?  If you don't know why your source said it was incorrect, you should say so in the question, as we have no clear idea what is giving you trouble.

Comment: Rather than asking about various examples over and over again, merely asking, "Is this correct?", it would be better to try to pinpoint what you are struggling with, and ask a more general question that focuses on the broader issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your source that claims the sentence is ungrammatical is incorrect.  That pattern is used frequently.

> He's a good man to have on such a project.
>
> It's the best tool to use for that purpose.
>
> It was the worst choice to have made in those circumstances.
>
> It was the thing to do.

An infinitive clause can complement the noun phrase.